# Monitoring Main(UI) Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, debugging

I have navigation application. Sometimes, some method(s) blocks ui thread.

How i can get list of methods that currently runs on Main Thread (or history)?

I tried [Method Tracer](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-methodtrace.html) but for some reason it create trace report for short period(0-3 seconds).  I need some way to know what methods was runs on main thread for last 1-5 min.

I tried [Traceview](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/traceview.html) also. For 20 seconds i got this picture:[image]

[image]

I don't really know how i can get list of my custom methods from this report

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

AndroidStudio has a profiling tool - DDMS. There is a TraceView utility for that.